# How do I fix or replace a misaligned ceramic cartridge tap whose measurements don't seem to fit a standard size?

Tags: leak, faucet, cartridge

We have a mixer tap ([this one](https://www.homebase.co.uk/homebase-gemma-twin-lever-chrome_p519505)) whose cold tap has started dripping water when turned off fully (i.e. when the handle is in the fully vertical position). We can completely stop this happening by adjusting the handle "on" by a couple of degrees so that the handle is very slightly off vertical, but still vertical. The tap also extends slightly down past the 90 degrees mark (so instead of turning the handle from a 12 o'clock position and stopping at full power at the 3 o'clock position, it goes to maybe the 3.30 position.

From looking at the brass ceramic cartridge on the inside of the tap ([2x pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwiZn.jpg)), the ceramic discs seem misaligned. When in the fully "closed" position, there is an opening (on the right in the 2nd picture) where water could seep through. I think it might be because the inside of the valve body has become worn, and is allowing the discs to rotate too far.

So, I think we have two options:

1. Fix the cartridge so that it's aligned properly; or
2. Get a replacement cartridge.

I'm happy with either fixing or buying a replacement. However, I'm not sure how to realign the cartridge (there doesn't seem anything obvious that I can adjust), and I'm also not sure which replacement cartridge is suitable for my needs. For example, according to the labels in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgESK.jpg), my measurements are as follows:

- 20 spline
- A: 45mm
- B: 24.5mm
- C: 20.5mm
- D: 17mm
- E: 22-23mm
- F: 10.5mm
- G: 16.5mm
- H: 20.5mm
- I: 7-7.5mm

We haven't been able to find any exact measurement matches in the products available on [sites like this](https://www.plumbers-mate-sales.co.uk/replacement-brass-valve-ceramic-disc-cartridges-130-c.asp). We're not sure which measurements need to exactly match vs which you have some wiggle room on.

Happy to provide any other information that's helpful - thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: The manufacturer (as far as I can tell) is Homebase themselves. The in-store customer service reps were did not have enough product knowledge to be able to answer the question, and I have not been able to get through to their central phone support due to COVID keeping their phone lines busy all the time.